# c++ std::cout doesn't print \n in string

Tags: c++, printing, cout

in my currrent project I load errors from a text file into a string array. But when I print them "\n" is print as "\n" and not as new line. Is there a way to fix this? Or is the only way to fix it to split the errors at every "\n" and to insert << std::endl <

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question with a [mcve] or [SSCCE (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example)](http://sscce.org)

Comment: It is likely how the text is formatted, but since you haven't provided us any code or sample text, I must vote to close.

Comment: Probably that "\n" is being escaped somehow (formatting maybe), but we can't do wild guesses. Provide some sample code!!

Answer (score 2):

> I load errors from a text file into a string array.

I assume you have these '\n's in your text file. So when they are read in they are stored in your strings as two characters, '\' and 'n'.  If you had these as literal strings in your code, then the compiler would have converted the '\n' to a new-line, and you would have the one 'new-line' character in your string.

So you will have to do this job yourself. I recommend doing it when you are reading your text file, not when doing the output. Look for back-slash, check the next character to see if it is one of the characters you want to convert (like 'n') then instead of storing the back-slash + character, store the new-line (or whatever).

I am sure that there are also libraries out there that will do this for you, either as part of the input, or output, or operating on the strings.